# Do Sacred Springs ever replenish?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

Occasionally, while dungeon-crawling, I'll come across a Sacred Spring or two. They give a unit of my choice a permanent stat increase or a free level up. Each one can be used 2-3 times before drying up. Will I ever be able to use a Sacred Spring after it dries up or is it done for good once it's dried up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Serenes Forest](https://serenesforest.net/fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia/miscellaneous/sacred-springs/), the only springs that can be used infinitely are the Fatigue Springs (in Duma Tower and Duma Temple).

All other springs are exhausted after 2 or 3 uses (depending on the spring), and aren't reusable without starting a new game.

Comment: I got really excited when you said infinite use springs, but then I checked and they're just for curing fatigue :(